# Using "amigui" instead of "amigo": Bien grax amigui

Tags: coloquialismos, sustantivos, honduras

A friend (woman) originating from Honduras asked me via mobile message how I was doing, to which I answered:

> Muy bien, y tu?

Her answer:

> **Bien grax amigui** que tengas un dia muy bonita!

**grax** is an abbreviation for **gracias**, but why **amigui** instead of **amigo**? (I am a guy)

- What is the difference compared with just using "amigo"?
- Is there a particular nuance?
- Is it a bit humorous?

Answer (score 2):

This is something I've started to hear recently, also in Spain. I think `amigui` is an abbreviation for `amiguito` which is, as JesusS says in his answer, more affectionate.

Answer (score 2):

**amigui** is not the short form for **amiguito**.

**amigui** is used for a more tender way to express **amigo(a)**.

Answer (score 2):

It's a trend way to talk. It's mainly used by girls and guys who are parodying that girls.

The *i* is used on a bunch of words like Hola-Holi, Amigo-amigui or even at laughing, like jijiji

Answer (score 1):

Amigui is like amigo but in a more affectionate way. "Amigui" as a word doesn't exist and I never used it, but in Spain we use to say "coleguis" instead of "colegas" (buddies) with the same nuance

Comment: If people speak and write "amigui" and other people understand it, then it most definitely is a word.  What else could it possibly be?  Whether you'll find it in a dictionary is another matter entirely.

Answer (score 1):

### Amigui:

> friend = amigo.
>
> dude = amigui.

It is the same "amigo", but with a more affectionate, as in the case of cat touch, kity, something good.

**denotes trust**

Answer (score 0):

**"Amigui"** is an abbreviation of **amiguito** (little friend), usually it is used to call a close friend an a friendly way.