# ¿Qué significa "amigui" en español?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, coloquialismos, españa

Estuve ligando con una chica alrededor de 3 meses y ya no nos vemos hace 5 meses pero vamos hablando a veces por mensajes. Hoy vamos a vernos otra vez.. pero ella me escribió en plan:

> Hello amigui, que plan tienes?

¿Qué significa este "amigui" en español? ¿Que ahora me ve como un amigo o es sólo una forma cariñosa de llamar?

¿"Amiguito/a" puede significar novio, amante, ligue?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Antes de darte una respuesta, necesito que me confirmes si la chica era de España. Aquí hay una moda últimamente de formar versiones cariñosas de las palabras con la terminación -i, pero no sé si pasará algo parecido en otros países de habla hispana.

Comment: @Charlie ¡y también en Honduras! [Using “amigui” instead of “amigo”: Bien grax amigui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15210/1674) lo que me hace pensar que seguramente se esté extendiendo su uso a toda la comunidad hispanohablante.

Comment: @fedorqui las cosas de Internet y el mundo globalizado: los cambios se propagan cada vez más rápido. No me había dado cuenta de que ya había una pregunta similar. Vmffb, ¿nos confirmas si te valen esas respuestas? Si prefieres una respuesta en español te la podemos dar, aunque seguramente luego procedamos a marcar la pregunta como duplicada.

Comment: @Charlie si, la chica es de España. Amigui es diminutivo de Amiguito ? Puede significar amante, novio, ligue?

Comment: @Charlie las respuestas del otro post no son muy claras. Es diminutivo de Amiguito? Porque si es, puede significar otra cosa, como amante o novio

Comment: Esta pregunta es duplicada de la que referencian los otros comentarios y en aquella la respuesta más acertada para hispanoamérica es la de @Ustanak

Answer (score 2):

En España, modificar los sustantivos para que terminen con *-i* es una moda actual, pero no implica nada más que mostrar cariño por parte de quien lo dice. No hace que la palabra cambie su significado ni que se esté implicando otra cosa. Sencillamente te está llamando "amigo", pero con cariño.

Otros ejemplos que se usan mucho por aquí:

> ¡*Besis*!
>
> ¡Claro que sí, *guapi*!

Por tanto, si te dice *amigui* significa *amigo* pero que te tiene cariño, nada más, no implica que quiera que seas su novio, amante o cualquier otra cosa. Nótese además que el caso de *besis* nos indica que la modificación de vocal no se forma como contracción (como podría ser el caso de *amigui* por *amiguito*), sino que sencillamente se está sustituyendo una vocal por otra (*besos* por *besis*).

También estoy viendo últimamente otros casos de modificaciones vocálicas, como el siguiente:

> ¡Ay, *par favar*, pero qué mono!

En este caso se deja entrever un exceso de ternura al cambiar las vocales por *a*.

Entrando ya en el terreno de la psicología, si tu preocupación es saber si la chica te considera como algo más que un amigo, no creo que se pueda deducir simplemente por el uso de *amigui*. Si usa *amigui* es porque te tiene confianza y se siente cómoda contigo, pero de ahí a suponer algo más creo que hay un gran paso. Deberás buscar pruebas más convincentes o tal vez preguntarle directamente.

Comment: Lo dicho vale también para Argentina: no tanto *amigui* pero sí *holis* (< *hola*) para saludar y *besis* para despedirse.